# Masonry Infinite Scroll different next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

I got a project with masonry infinite scroll from this url:
http://tutsmix.com/cool-css-loading-effects-for-grid-images/

i successfully implemented it in my page, however, the next page is puzzling me.

i am trying to navigate, at the end of my html i have

```
<nav class="pagination">
   <a class="next" href="index-02.php"></a>
</nav>
```

Now this works for the first time. 
in index-02.php, no matter what page i select, it will go for index-03.php

I am not able to know where is this counter adding up, or how to turn it off. i want to be able to select the page manually.

any advises?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just take the class=pagination off the ul, worked for me

p.s. you have it as `<nav>` they have it as `<ul>`

Comment: Thank you so much. pagination class seemed to do the trick...
nav and ul does not make a difference since the selection is based on the class.
cheers